# Display a part of the searched mongodb document in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to display a searched document that mongodb searched in EJS. But so far I only managed to show the entire document at once as a json format. But now I want to display only one part of that instead of the whole document. But for some reason why I try to display just a part of it the field would stay empty when you preview it in the browser. The field in this case is: "otherusername".  For this I am using: nodejs, mongodb, express and EJS.

Index.js:

```js
router.post('/searchplayer', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
const {text} = req.body;
var input = text
User.findOne({charactername: text})
.then(user => {
if(user) {
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
console.log('player found')
MongoClient.connect(url, function(error, db) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var dbo = db.db("Databasetest");
  var query = { charactername: text };
  dbo.collection("users").find(query).toArray(function(error, query, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(query, null , 12)
    console.log(myJSON);
    res.render('playersearch',  {
      user: req.user,
      energy: myJSON.energy
    })
    console.log(energy)
    db.close();
  })
});
} else {
console.log("Player does not exist")
res.redirect('main')
}
})
})
```

What happens here is that someone makes a search by typing in a name and once it is found in MongoDB in the collection "users" it will redirect you to another page. Where it should render out the information that belongs to that name that was searched. But the problem is that I am not able to show a single field in EJS, so to clarify the myJSON is the entire document that was found by MongoDB which is stringified.

In this case I tried to show the energy field because it exists in that document, but this will just return a empty field in the "otherusername" field. What I also tried was to write in the field for example: myJSON.energy but this would also return a empty field for some reason when I would preview it in the browser.

playersearch.ejs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="/static/CSS/styleofplayersearch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
     <title>test</title>
     <img id= "backgroundimage"  draggable="false" src="/static/images/post_apocalyptic_landscape.jpg">  
     <div id= "blackbackground"  draggable="false"></div>  

    <h4 id="otherusername"><%=energy%></h4> 
 
    


<script>
</script>





    <a id="logouttext" href="/users/logout">Logout</a> 
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is how could I render just one part of the document that Mongodb found instead of the whole document?

Comment: Try using JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringfy.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of what you're experiencing is that you're creating a string (the output of JSON.stringify) and then trying to access the "energy" property of that string which is undefined. You include that undefined value in what you pass to your EJS template and then try to render it, which causes EJS to render undefined, causing nothing to appear. Your EJS code looks good, it's just that you're not sending the template the right data.

Instead of serializing the entire matched document from MongoDB and passing that string to your EJS template as you render it, you can pass the object itself. The rendering system can handle that. Then, in the EJS file, you use dot notation to access only the properties you want to render. You should use this technique to render the "energy" property from that object it belongs to in your example.

A good practice is to only pass the data you need to render to the templating system, especially if sensitive data is involved. So in that example you would pass just the energy property to the templating system as you call render.

Comment: Well if  I dont  stringfy the document ejs would just say: object Object.  And I am not entirely sure how  I would be able to do what you said, could you give me a small example of how this would be possible?

Comment: If  I try that then the error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1   comes up.

Comment: EJS calls toString on what you tell it to render. That's why you see "Object object" when you tell it to render an object. If you use dot notation to access the properties one at a time in the EJS code, it will be able to render the properties in ways that look good.

Comment: Something like this you mean for example?:  "bar": "some string"

Comment: Example: https://ejs.co/ (scroll down to where it shows the example with `<h2><%= user.name %></h2>`)

Comment: Yeah I tried to do that like this for example:<h2><%= myJSON.energy%></h2>  but then the field stays empty when I see it in the browser.

Comment: Even when I dont stringify it and I render just query instead and use query.energy the field remains empty in the browser. Its so weird because if i just only use query I would see the entire document. But once I try to view a part of it then there is just nothing.

Comment: I don't understand why you would see the entire matched document if you render "query" because that variable appears to be your prepared MongoDB query. It shouldn't represent a matched document. You'll probably need to use some debugging techniques in your Express handler to find out exactly what data you have when the MongoDB query finishes so that you can choose what to render. Don't forget that if you want to render the query results and some other data, you'll have to call render with an object comprised of the results and that other data (like the string used as part of the query).

Comment: Well what I did is that the user searches the name of a person. And so I defined query as the input of what someone searches. Then it uses that input and looks in to the collection "users" to see if that input of the search comes up in any of the current documents that are located in the user collection. If so then it would redirect you to another page where it renders that specific document which has the field that matches what the person searched for. If that makes any sense.

Comment: It's pretty hard to see exactly what's going on in your app. I lack context. The EJS docs examples show you how to render the data if you pass it to the render function as you call it. It's up to you to know the data you're passing and make sure it's passed correctly. I suggest taking a step back and using debugging techniques (like console logging variables or observing variables in the debugger in an IDE) so that you can understand exactly how you're calling render.

Comment: Yeah  I will try that thanks for the advice.

Comment: Also, now that I'm on my desktop, I notice that you may be publishing the credentials for your MongoDB database in `const url = '<redacted>';`. That code was present in a few other questions you asked too. You should delete it from the questions and re-create your MongoDB database. Even if it's just a test, people can log into it and save bad things in it. You never want to include host name or password when you share things like that on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Comment: Oh shit yeah you're right oh well.. I wanted to make a new one anyway this was more for testing. But thanks for all of you're help! :)